# I've created a button using js to narrow or widen the width of page but not working

Tags: javascript, html

What's the problem here?
It **correctly works** when `onload` function runs but **not** when `myFunction` runs.

**JS** file with `defer` attribute inside `<head>` :

```
let cont = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
let isit = localStorage.getItem("isit");
let button = document.getElementById("nawi");

window.onload = function () {
    if (isit == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 0);
    }
    if (isit == 0) {
        cont.style.width = "100%";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 0);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it narrow";
        console.log(isit);
    } else {
        cont.style.width = "1000px";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 1);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it wide";
        console.log(isit);
    }
};

function myFunction() {
    if (isit == 0) {
        cont.style.width = "1000px";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 1);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it wide";
        console.log(isit);
    }
    if (isit == 1) {
        cont.style.width = "100%";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 0);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it narrow";
        console.log(isit);
    }
}
```

**HTML** file:

```
       <button onclick="myFunction()" id="nawi"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button you aren't changing the value of the variable `isit`

This means that although you are changing the localStorage value it is not reflected in the JavaScript so it is running the same section of the if statement each time you click the button.

Change the function to this.

```
function myFunction() {
    if (isit == 0) {
        cont.style.width = "1000px";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 1);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it wide";
        console.log(isit);
    }
    else {
        cont.style.width = "100%";
        localStorage.setItem("isit", 0);
        button.innerHTML = "Make it narrow";
        console.log(isit);
    }
    isit = localStorage.getItem("isit");
}
```

Currently what happens is it checks to see if `isit == 0` and then chang

Comment: Btw, after ```else``` you forgot to delete the parentheses.

Comment: Happy to help .

Comment: @AlpayNamazi What do you mean exactly?

Comment: ```else (isit == 1) {``` this line.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yea of course ;)